# Firefox server not found but wifi is working?

Tags: networking

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm brand new to Ubuntu. Please assume I have zero knowledge about this OS.

My computer says I'm connected to wifi, but when I launch Firefox and search for anything the page returns "Server not found".

There was no problem with the internet when this laptop was running Windows 10.  I've tried the classic reboot and it's not a router issue either, as every other non-Ubuntu computer or device in my house is having no trouble with the internet. I have also reset the router as well.

[image: ]]

Comment: Please run `ifconfig -a` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` in a terminal and add the output to your question

Comment: Please provide the output of these three commands: **1)** `ping -c5 8.8.8.8`, **2)** `host 8.8.8.8`, and **3)** `host google.com`.

Comment: I have updated my question by attaching a photo taken by my iphone, of the commands you guys requested that I enter in the terminal.